# Media Query in Atom

Tags: css, media-queries

I have an issue with my .css code in ATOM.

When I write the @media Query that doesn't have any effect in response size (mobile)

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 1436px){

  #title{
    text-align: center;
  }

  .title-image{
    width: 60%;
    transform: rotate(0);
    position: static;
  }

}
```

The webpage remain with the values wrote before the query:

```
    #title{

  background-color: #ff4c68;
  color: #fff;

}
```

---

```
    .title-image{

  width: 18%;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 450px;

}
```

could you have any solution?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: is the media-query at the bottom of your CSS file?

Comment: Hi! 
Nope the media-query is at final of the code but I tried on top of .title-image as well

Comment: Actually when I change the browser to EDGE media-query works fine but in Chrome still appear like no-media-query.